# Need help with a problem on integrability of derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $$f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$$ and $$g(x) = |f(x)|^{r-1} f(x)$$$r \in \mathbb{N}$. It is known that $g\in \mathcal{L}^2(0,1)$ and the $r^{th}$ weak derivative, $ g^{(r)} \in \mathcal{L}^2(0,1)$ with $\|g^{(r)}\|_{L^2} > 0$. I need help to show that the first weak derivative $f^{(1)} \in \mathcal{L}^{2r}(0,1)$

PS : 1. : If I differentiate $g$ $r$ times, apart from other terms (in sum) I get a term $f'(x)^r$, so I am trying to get the result, if I could prove that all other terms also are integrable.

2. Also since it is a $L^2$ norm, can I leverage the asymptotics of Fourier series coefficients to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I will only consider the case $r=2$. Hope it will inspire you for the general $r$ case.

Suppose $f$ is a smooth function with support contained in $(0, 1)$. Then $g$ is also supported in $(0, 1)$.  Then we see that
\begin{align}
4\int^1_0|f(x)f'(x)|^2\ dx=&\ \int^1_0 (g'(x))^2\ dx \\
=&\ g(x)g'(x)\bigg|^1_0 -\int^1_0 g(x)g''(x)\ dx = -\int^1_0 g(x) g''(x)\ dx.
\end{align}
In particular, we see that
\begin{align}
\left|\int^1_0 g(x) g''(x)\ dx \right| \leq&\ \left(\int^1_0 |g(x)|^2\ dx \right)^{1/2}\left(\int^1_0 |g''(x)|^2\ dx \right)^{1/2}.
\end{align}
Hence by the hypotheses, we see that 
\begin{align}
\int^1_0 |f(x)f'(x)|^2\ dx <\infty
\end{align}

Next, by direct calculation, we see 
\begin{align}
g'(x) = 2|f(x)|f'(x) \ \ \text{ and } \ \ g''(x) = 2\frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}\left\{(f'(x))^2+f(x)f''(x)\right\}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\left(\int^1_0 |g''(x)|^2\ dx\right)^{1/2} =&\  2\left(\int^1_0 \left| (f'(x))^2+f(x)f''(x)\right|^2 dx\right)^{1/2}.
\end{align}
Thus, we have that
\begin{align}
\left(\int^1_0|f'(x)|^4 dx\right)^{1/2}\leq \frac{1}{2}\left(\int^1_0 |g''(x)|^2\ dx\right)^{1/2}+\left(\int^1_0|f(x)f''(x)|^2\ dx \right)^{1/2}.
\end{align}